# How to say "second-latest" version?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I am writing a paper where I must say that I am using Software 11, but the latest  version is Software 12. So, how should I say that X 11 is the "second-latest" version?

Sentence:

"at the moment of writing, Software 11 is the [...], with the lasted version being Software 12."

Answer (score 2):

You could say "Software 11 is the [penultimate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate) version." Penultimate means next-to-last.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "... version 11, the most recent precursor to the current version 12. ..."
Better to just put them in separate sentences:
"... version 11. The current release is version 12. ..."

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most natural phrasing of your construction is the following:

> Software 11 is the *previous version* of the current Software release.

---

This sounds better if replaced by a real example:

> Windows 8 is the previous version of the current Windows release.